# Gradle manage transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

I'm relatively new to gradle and I have a situation in which I have a (gradle) project and I would like to use junit 4.13 or higher (for assert throws).  You can find the project here: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/master/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/build.gradle  The issue is that one of the dependencies of the project brings in junit 4.12, so this ends up on my classpath from the transitive dependency (I've verified this using the project report plugin).  I'm trying to remove junit 4.12 from the classpath using the following methods, but to no avail (find the results next to each):

- adding an exclusion to the dependency bringing in junit.12 transitively -> this results in 4.12 still being present on classpath, and still being brought in from this dependency:

`implementation('io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson') { exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'}`

- adding a (strict) constraint to force the upgrade of the minor version -> says cannot find dependency to satisfy contraints (see below):

`constraints{ //force upgrade to junit 4.13 for compatibility (and gives us assertThrows) implementation("junit:junit") { because "4.13 has assertThrows" version { strictly "$junitVersion" } } }`

Error log for trying to force upgrade:
`Could not resolve all files for configuration ':reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:testCompileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.13.
> Required by:
> project :reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl
> > Cannot find a version of 'junit:junit' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'com.connor:reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'junit:junit:4.13'
> Constraint path 'com.connor:reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'junit:junit:{strictly 4.13}' because of the following reason: 4.13 has assertThrows
> Constraint path 'com.connor:reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:1.7.1.Final' --> 'junit:junit:4.12'

> Could not resolve junit:junit:{strictly 4.13}.
> Required by:
> project :reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl
> > Cannot find a version of 'junit:junit' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'com.connor:reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'junit:junit:4.13'
> Constraint path 'com.connor:reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'junit:junit:{strictly 4.13}' because of the following reason: 4.13 has assertThrows
> Constraint path 'com.connor:reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:1.7.1.Final' --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
> `

**Can anyone help me force my project to use junit 4.13 (or higher)?**  Thanks.

Side note:
I suspect this might be an issue with this being a maven native project, so there might be issues with transitive dependencies (as in maven, there is no api vs implementation scopes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason JUnit 4.12 is resolving instead of a higher version (4.13) is because of this line: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/master/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/build.gradle#L43

You are enforcing constraints from this platform (BOM) which defines JUnit 4.12 as a constraint: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom/1.7.0.Final/pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

If you merely want to use the platform as a "recommendations", then `platform` should be used instead:

```
implementation(platform("..."))
```

For future, you can use the `dependencyInsight` task to figure out why Gradle is selecting a particular version of a dependency:

```
./gradlew :reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:dependencyInsight --dependency junit:junit --configuration testCompileClasspath
```

Running the above gives:

```
> Task :reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl:dependencyInsight
junit:junit:4.13
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 11
   ]
   Selection reasons:
      - By constraint
      - By conflict resolution : between versions 4.13 and 4.12

junit:junit:4.13
\--- testCompileClasspath

junit:junit:4.12 -> 4.13
\--- io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:1.7.0.Final
     \--- testCompileClasspath

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

The important bits for this question are:

```
Selection reasons:
          - By constraint
          - By conflict resolution : between versions 4.13 and 4.12
```

Because the platform is enforced and there is a conflict in versions, the platform constraint will win.

Further reading: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_consumption

Comment: Wow, very thorough (and insightful) answer Francisco.  As someone who is (relatively) new to gradle, I really appreciate the help.  

(Upvoted and accepted)